# How to search a string in a specific file type in VSCode?

Tags: search, visual-studio-code, file-type

It should be quite simple, but sometimes I found that searches in VSCode do not work as expected.

In this below example, I just want to search the string `stat` in all the `JavaScript` files in the folder `./ocean-data-qc/ocean_data_qc_js`. But, in the search results, I get files of all kind of types:

[image]

I also want to search in the subfolders files.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I think you used a "," instead of a "/" in your pattern. And I wouldn't use the "./" at the beginning.
```ocean-data-qc/ocean_data_qc_js/*.js``` would be the right pattern

Comment: @olivier Thanks for answering. The pattern with comma used to work in the past. Did they change it? I want to search also in subfolders. This may be the right pattern `./ocean-data-qc/ocean_data_qc_js/**/*.js`. In fact, I get different results with and without the `./` at the beginning. I believe, with `./`, the file `.gitignore` is not taken into account

Comment: I have just checked, with the comma and without `./` works fine as well. So I think that's the problem. The funny thing is that when you click on one folder with the right button and press in the option "Find in Folder..." the app adds those characters (`./`) at the beginning

Comment: I think the comma aims to list different patterns : ```path1/**/*.js, path2/**/*.js``` will search in all the js under path1 or path2

Comment: @olivier You are right, it works like a logical `or` instead of `and`. I have read [the documention](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files). Without `./` at the beginning, for instance `example`, will match every folder and file named like that. So, the only valid pattern should be `./ocean-data-qc/ocean_data_qc_js/**/*.js`, but this is not taking into account the `.gitignore` file. I would need to add the `search.exclude` to the settings

Comment: Although it says "Also note the Use Exclude Settings and Ignore Files toggle button in the files to exclude box. The toggle determines whether to exclude files that are ignored by your `.gitignore` files". But it is not working for some reason

Comment: I have found the issue with `.gitignore` @olivier and I have answered my own question with all the details. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the expression `./ocean-data-qc/ocean_data_qc_js,*.js` it will search across all the files of the path `./ocean-data-qc/ocean_data_qc_js` and then it will search on all the js files of the project. The result will be the union of both searches

Instead, the pattern should be `./ocean-data-qc/ocean_data_qc_js/**/*.js` to make just one search in all the js files in the folder and subfolders. But it is not working as expected because the files in the `.gitignore` are included in the search. So, in some way, the pattern in the include section is overriding the excluded paths.

I have found an issue to answer why the [`.gitignore` is not taken into account](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26574) in that case. As I am working in multiroot mode, I found two solutions that work:

- Just using the root folder of the project where I am searching: `./ocean-data-qc/**/*.js`. Like this `.gitignore` is taken into account.
- The other alternative is to use the `search.exclude` attribute in the VScode settings.

**Note**: The important sections in the VSCode docs: [Multiroot search](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_search). [Advanced search options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options)